# How can I print the most populous state from my structure?

Tags: c++, structure

I need to print the most populous state out of 3 that are inputted by the user. I need to do that by using a structure and comparing the populations of the three states that are also inputted by the user. It does not run but does not give any errors either. The compiler just times out.

```
struct state_struct {
    string name;
    int pop;
};

int main()
{
    state_struct state[3];
    int i;
    string mystr, print_most_pop;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter name of state:" << endl;
        getline(cin, state[i].name);
        cout << "Enter population for state:" << endl;
        getline(cin, mystr);
        stringstream(mystr) >> state[i].pop;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (state[i].pop > state[i + 1].pop && state[i].pop >state[i+2].pop)
            print_most_pop = state[i].name;
        if (state[i].pop > state[i + 1].pop && state[i].pop < state[i + 
        2].pop)
            print_most_pop = state[i + 2].name;
        if (state[i].pop < state[i + 1].pop && state[i].pop > state[i + 
        2].pop)
            print_most_pop = state[i + 1].name;
     }
    cout << "The most populous state you entered is " << print_most_pop << 
    endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int i;for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` is something C compilers required before C99. Don't use it here. Similarly, you don't need to use getline when you can do `string name; string pop; cin >> state[i].name >> state[i].pop;`

Comment: Where you do want to separate `i` from the loop it indexes is cases where you want to use `i` outside the loop. For example, when you want to know how many `i`s you counted.

Comment: Hint: When `i = 1` in the second loop, what does the index `i + 2` access? When `i = 2`, then what does the index `i + 1` access? (Remember your array bounds here)

Comment: Yes. It is for a homework assignment that requires structures.

Comment: Fyi, you don't need an array for this in the first place. And you don't need two loops. Read the first state, it is the initial "leader". Then, read all the other states, one at a time (this is your only loop). After each read, if the just-read population exceeds the current leader, save it as the new leader and continue on. When you're done, the leader will be known.

Comment: Cheap trick: If you point at the biggest state you've seen so far (eg `state_struct * biggeststate = &state[0];`) then you just have to test to see if subsequent states are bigger than the biggest  and replace the biggest as necessary (eg `if (biggeststate->pop < state[i].pop) biggeststate = &state[i];`) and when you're out of states, print out the biggest state.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's comments, but I am still unable to run the program correctly. @ArnavBorborah I used your hint and removed the for loop, so now there shouldn't be any bounds on it. It still just times out.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to get this program running correctly? There are a lot of good suggestions in these comments.

Comment: @JustinRandall I was. I'm at a point where I understand the logic behind how my programs should be written but run into walls because of the lack of programming experience I have. Thank you for your help as well!

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop here and just keep track of your biggest population as entered. You also don't need to do any convoluted computations to determine the maximum, just simply if n.pop > current_max then set your current_max to n.  You also can put your `int pop` directly into the structure from `cin`, no need to convert it from string to stringstream. You can loop until the input is actually an integer type to be sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

struct state_struct {
    string name;
    int pop;
};

int main()
{
    state_struct state[3];
    state_struct biggest {"none", 0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter name of state:" << endl;
        getline(cin, state[i].name);
        cout << "Enter popuation for state:" << endl;
        // make sure population is an integer type
        while(!(cin >> state[i].pop))
        {
            cout << "Invalid value! Please enter a number." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

        if (state[i].pop > biggest.pop)
        {
            biggest = state[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "The most populous state is " << biggest.name << " with " << biggest.pop << endl;
    return 0;
}
```